# How to change log4j2 pattern in a running application

Tags: java, log4j2, log4j

im searching for a possibilty to change the log4j2 date format in a already running application. I need it for a client where a user can choose between different languages. Depending on his choice i would like to change the pattern (layout) which is currently (just an example) configured as

`<Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">

<PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />

</Console>`

Does anybody have a hint/clue how to do this? I couldn't find any resources yet as log4j *1* is used mostly....

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this is the right way as the API may lack this option at the moment, but it works for me:

XML:

```
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Java:

```
logger.info("hey!");

LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration conf = ctx.getConfiguration();
Appender console = conf.getAppenders().get("console");   // <-- your appender name
PatternLayout layout = (PatternLayout) console.getLayout();

layout.setConversionPattern("%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n");

ctx.updateLoggers(conf);

logger.info("hey!");
```

The result:

```
14:02:00.343 [main] INFO  test.Log4j2Sample - hey!
14:02:00 [main] INFO  test.Log4j2Sample - hey!
```

Comment: The method `setConversionPattern` does not exist (anymore?).

Answer (score 0):

Log4j 2 has a configuration attribute for that

log4j2.xml:

```
<Configuration monitorInterval="5">
    ...
</Configuration>
```

log4j 2 will automatically re-read whole configuration every monitorInterval seconds